# Video seeking problems in air for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, video, air

I'm developing a video app for android using flash pro (air).
I have a problem when trying to seek the video, it seems that air keeps a certain amount of video data in memory and won't let me seek before that buffer. Here's a video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLkTA96r2jU
The code is very basic and works perfectly on the desktop. What can I do to keep all of the downloaded video in memory?

Comment: Unfortunately AIR isn't great with video on Android. I would advise you to look into using an ANE for video. Take a look at Distriqt Media Player ANE.

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks!